# Is there any perfect plugin for Socket IO implementation in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, socket.io

I want to implement socket IO in my Flutter app,
I got succeed in Android with [flutter_socket_io](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_socket_io), but it is not working on iOS,

Then i have tried [socket_flutter_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/socket_flutter_plugin) and [adhara_socket_io](https://pub.dev/packages/adhara_socket_io) any of these plugins are not working on both platforms.

I have also tried [socket_io_client](https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client) but still it is not working.

I followed all steps written in readme of all plugins. but still any of those are not working.

I have checked all issues for respective plugins and tried to follow them as well.

Does anyone used socket IO in Flutter at both platforms (Android and iOS).

Comment: I assume you read https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_socket_io#how-to-install-on-ios already?

Comment: Yes i have already did and followed all steps.
Did not worked for me.

Comment: What's the exact issue you're facing? Can you post the logs?

Comment: All plugins have different issues,
Mostly i get `Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method socketInit on channel flutter_socket_io)`

Comment: This issue is related to channel. Flutter is not able to find the specific channel while invoking a method. So basically it means that you're missing something in integration. Do one thing take a blank project and try to integrate the same library in other project.

Comment: I have created a blank project and working on it since 4 days, Still unable to find solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have managed to resolve this issue with [socket_io_client](https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client) plugin, it is dart level library and works well out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you haven't tried using the Dart [Socket](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-io/Socket-class.html) implementation in [dart:io](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-io/dart-io-library.html)? It works out of the box and you don't need to configure a third-party plugin.

Comment: As it is very high level classes i didn't used them as they we have limited time, but somehow we managed to resolve this issue.